# Soft link in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, symlink, hardlink

Is there some equivalent in Mercurial to NIX soft- or hard- links to directories or files.

Basically that a file (or directory) is linked to a file "somewhere else" and follows the version of that location (Unlike a regular branch I think, where one would have to merge)

Answer (score 12):

Mercurial versions soft links that are internal to the repository just great.  It'll detect them, record them, and create them for you.  Is there a specific use case you're looking for?  The closest thing to an link that reaches outside the repository is a subrepo, which is a pointer to a specific version of another repo.

**Symlinks work**

```
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:~ ry4an$ hg init olav
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:~ ry4an$ cd olav/
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ echo this > target
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ ln -s target link
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ ls -l
total 16
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ry4an  staff     6B Feb 16 19:25 link@ -> target
-rw-r--r--  1 ry4an  staff     5B Feb 16 19:25 target
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ hg commit -A -m "link and its target"
adding link
adding target
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ hg log -p
changeset:   0:42a41a431661
tag:         tip
user:        Ry4an Brase <ry4an-hg@ry4an.org>
date:        Sat Feb 16 19:26:17 2013 -0500
summary:     link and its target

diff -r 000000000000 -r 42a41a431661 link
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/link  Sat Feb 16 19:26:17 2013 -0500
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+target
\ No newline at end of file
diff -r 000000000000 -r 42a41a431661 target
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/target    Sat Feb 16 19:26:17 2013 -0500
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+this

(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ hg update null
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ ls -l
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ hg update tip
2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(df)Ry4ans-MacBook-Air:olav ry4an$ ls -l
total 16
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ry4an  staff     6B Feb 16 19:26 link@ -> target
-rw-r--r--  1 ry4an  staff     5B Feb 16 19:26 target
```

**But hardlinks don't**

```
$hg commit -Am "hardlinks target"
adding link
adding target
$hg log -p
changeset:   0:ec9407634133
tag:         tip
user:        Chris Wesseling <chris.wesseling@cwi.nl>
date:        Wed Mar 13 23:14:44 2013 +0100
summary:     hardlinks target

diff -r 000000000000 -r ec9407634133 link
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/link      Wed Mar 13 23:14:44 2013 +0100
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+foo
diff -r 000000000000 -r ec9407634133 target
--- /dev/null   Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970 +0000
+++ b/target    Wed Mar 13 23:14:44 2013 +0100
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+foo

$ls -lin
total 8
276702 -rw-r--r-- 2 1204653 5900 4 13 mrt 23:14 link
276702 -rw-r--r-- 2 1204653 5900 4 13 mrt 23:14 target
$hg update null
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 2 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$hg update tip
2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
$ls -lin
total 8
276719 -rw-r--r-- 1 1204653 5900 4 13 mrt 23:15 link
276721 -rw-r--r-- 1 1204653 5900 4 13 mrt 23:15 target
```

Comment: You mean it will handle NIX soft links in the files it is versioning?

Comment: Thanks for the update @chris-wesseling They asked about soft/sym links, but having ht hardlink info is good too.

Answer (score 10):

## Path auditing on *nix

On *nix systems, [`hg` Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/guide/) audits symbolic links *("symlinks")* for referred path security.
For example, **absolute and empty paths are considered unsafe** and will therefore not be added to the repository.

Mercurial developers have not documented this feature. However, [the source code contains a comment](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/file/f15c646bffc7/mercurial/scmutil.py#l61) with a somewhat vague explanation:

```
class pathauditor(object):
    '''ensure that a filesystem path contains no banned components.
    the following properties of a path are checked:

    - ends with a directory separator
    - under top-level .hg
    - starts at the root of a windows drive
    - contains ".."
    - traverses a symlink (e.g. a/symlink_here/b)
    - inside a nested repository (a callback can be used to approve
      some nested repositories, e.g., subrepositories)
    '''
```

On Windows, symbolic links are not supported for various reasons, see:

- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue1825
- https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue2579

Comment: Symbolic links to absolute paths can be added to a mercurial repo.  I don't know what "empty paths" means in this context.