# Mercurial pull/checkout results in broken symbolic links

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, mercurial, cocoapods

Sometimes when merging two branches in a Mercurial repository all symbolic links get corrupted, the resulting file is a file containing the path to the file instead of a proper symbolic link. This renders a failed build since the compiler will try to parse and build the file containing a path to the file it should have been compiling, hence compiling fails. Usually this renders all of the CocoaPods used corrupted and in some cases some of the pre-compiled frameworks that are stored in the repo are also corrupted - the fix is to perform a fresh install of pods *pod install* or sometimes just *pod update* will do. The same goes for pre-compiled frameworks, these have to be imported again into the project and hence overwriting the corrupt framework's files.

Is there any way to solve this without migrating from Mercurial?

Comment: Don't use symlinks at all?!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961016/how-to-treat-a-symbolic-link-as-a-directory-in-mercurial and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908763/soft-link-in-mercurial